# pycharm error while running python programs

Tags: python, pycharm

Getting below error while running any python program from Pycharm

Please help how to over come this

Thanks

```
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/home/XXX/anaconda3/envs/pylearn/lib/python3.10/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXX/anaconda3/envs/pylearn/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1560, in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Comment: Did you press `Ctrl+C`(Or `Cmd+c`)? It seems to be a keyboard interrupt

Comment: nope. Getting this always for every program run in pycharm